# What space-time points should a known coefficient function be evaluated at when using the Lax-Friedrichs scheme to solve the transport equation?

Tags: pde, finite-difference, numerics, hyperbolic-pde

For a scalar quantity $u = u(x, t)$, I'm considering the transport equation
\begin{align}
u_t + au_x &= 0, \qquad{x\in[0, L], \ t\in[0, T]}
\\
u(0, t) &= u_{\text{in}},
\\
u(x, 0) &= f(x).
\end{align}
When $a$ is a constant, the Lax-Friedrichs scheme is the FTCS approximation given by
\begin{equation}\label{PDE}
u_j^{n + 1} = \frac{u_{j + 1}^n + u_{j - 1}^{n}}{2} - \frac{a(u_{j + 1}^n - u_{j - 1}^{n})}{2},
\end{equation}
where $u_j^n = u(x_j, t^n)$ for equally spaced space-time mesh points.

In the case $a = a(x, t)$, what are the values of $x_j,\ t^n$ that $a$ should be evaluated at? Given the scheme is forward in time, I can reasonably convince myself that we evaluate $a$ in time as
$$
a(x, t^{n + 1}),
$$
but which space point should we use? The implicit-in-space nature of the Lax-Friedrichs scheme prevents me from using the same logic as I have with time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this as the canonical generalisation
$$
u_t(x_j,t_n) \approx \frac{u_j^{n+1} - (u_{j-1}^n + u_{j+1}^n)/2}{\Delta t}
$$

$$
(a u_x)(x_j,t_n) \approx a(x_j, t_n) \frac{u_{j+1}^n - u_{j-1}^n}{2\Delta x}
$$

$$
u_j^{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(u_{j-1}^n + u_{j+1}^n) - \frac{a_j^n \Delta t}{2\Delta x} (u_{j+1}^n - u_{j-1}^n)
$$

Answer (score 0):

See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax–Friedrichs_method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method), in which the extension to nonlinear conservation laws is described. You may also want to check out the large number of articles that use the LF-method for non-linear conservation laws using Google.